# NavmeshAgent not updating Destination, unless specific Vector3

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
void SetDestination () {
    ReverseDir = (Player.transform.position)*-1;
    Destination = Player.transform.position;

    if (!BigDotScript.RunAway){
        _NavMeshAgent.SetDestination (Destination);
        Debug.Log ("No run");
    }

    if (BigDotScript.RunAway){
        _NavMeshAgent.SetDestination (ReverseDir);
        Debug.Log ("run");

    }
}
```

I have this code, now it runs fine aside from when setting the destination to ReverseDir. The NavmeshAgent completely ignores the destination and carries on as if SetDestinantion=Destination, If I set ReverseDir to

```
    ReverseDir = new Vector3(0,0,0);
```

it works however, any ideas?

Also as a side note the effect I'm trying to achieve is the avoidance of the Player gameobject, if there is a better way than this I'm all ears! Many thanks

Comment: Probably because `Player.transform.position * -1` doesn't exist on the nav mesh.

Comment: Of course, how stupid of me! Any ideas how I can get the desired effect?

Comment: The navmesh code that exists in Unity isn't good for handling "run away from target" code. Its only good at "running towards." You'd have to set up a place to run *away to* or write your own agent code.

Answer (score 0):

I had same issue, in my case, my destination everytime was 0, until agent reached his point. When he reached point, Debug.Log() said, that the distance is 0.4994949. So i did this thing:

```
if (agent.remainingDistance == 0f && time == 100000)
    {
        agent.speed = 1f;
        Debug.Log(agent.remainingDistance);
        animator.SetFloat("Blend", 1);
        GotoNextPoint();
        if (time == 99000 && animator.GetFloat("Blend") == 0)
        {
            time = 10000;
            animator.SetFloat("Blend", 1);
            GotoNextPoint();
        }
    }
    else if (agent.remainingDistance <= 0.5f && agent.remainingDistance != 0f && time == 100000)
    {
        animator.SetFloat("Blend",0);
        agent.enabled = false;
        GotoNextPoint();
    }
```

Comment: EDIT: do not pay attention to "time" and different animator's properties. You need just what only in IF ARGUMENTS